# Using element.size in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm running `element.size` for images in selenium in [like here](https://www.ebay.com)

and I'm getting this:

> {'height': 0.0, 'width': 0.0} {'height': 1.0, 'width': 1.0}

any idea??

Comment: Which images? Share exact code

Comment: Relevant HTML and code trials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.size` returns 'width and height of the rendered element'.

check if you really referring to 'image' element while printing. Those elements must be having `img` tags.

**Also, wait for the element to be displayed using WebDriverWait.**

The element highlighted in below screenshot returned size as `(150, 30)`

CSS locator for the element: `[src*='FC_PrimeTime-25off119-FlashCoupon_Doodle_150x30_FINAL.png']`

[image]